# Should Paul 'I say' be considered a doctrine or opinion

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul

When Paul was giving instructions in various places in the Bible he often switches between "the Lord says" and "I say, not from the Lord", would it be right to consider his opinions of "I say, not from the Lord" as placeholders which we can substitute with our personal preferences today?

An example is this in 1 Corinthians 7:

> 12 Now, I will speak to the rest of you, though I do not have a direct
> command from the Lord. If a fellow believer has a wife who is not a
> believer and she is willing to continue living with him, he must not
> leave her. 13 And if a believing woman has a husband who is not a
> believer and he is willing to continue living with her, she must not
> leave him.

Should opinions like this be considered as Christian doctrines or personal? Should statements like this be given regard as a doctrine or just an opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the context, NIV 1 Corinthians 7:

> 6 **I say this** as a concession, not as a command. 7 **I wish** that all of you were as I am. But each of you has your own gift from God; one has this gift, another has that.

Paul was not pushing a doctrine here. It could not be that Paul commanded every Christian to stay single as he was. Here I-say-this is compared to I-wish.
He was being clear: he was not making a command.

A few verses later:

> 12 To the rest **I say this** (I, not the Lord): If any brother has a wife who is not a believer and she is willing to live with him, he must not divorce her. 13And if a woman has a husband who is not a believer and he is willing to live with her, she must not divorce him.

Here too, Paul was not pressing a doctrine but it was good advice from an apostle with the authority of an apostle.

Should statements like this be given regard as a doctrine or just an opinion?

Not as a doctrine and not just as an opinion either but as a piece of good advice from Apostle Paul.

Comment: Your supposition is very good, please use the reference I provided for this explanation.

Comment: What reference?

Answer (score 1):

#### Should Paul 'I say' be considered a doctrine or opinion

In the article "Inspiration" in the *Insight on the Scriptures* under the heading "[Is the fact that Bible writers showed individuality in expression consistent with the Bible’s being inspired by God?](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002178#h=18)"

> This may be seen by the expressions the apostle Paul makes in his first letter to the Corinthians. In giving counsel on marriage and singleness he says at one point: “But to the others I say, yes, I, not the Lord . . . ” Again: “Now concerning virgins I have no command from the Lord, but I give my opinion.” And finally, regarding a widowed woman, he states: “But she is happier if she remains as she is, according to my opinion. I certainly think I also have God’s spirit.” ([1Co 7:12,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002178/47/0) [25,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002178/47/1) [40](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002178/47/2)) **The evident meaning of Paul’s statements is that he could quote no direct teaching by the Lord Jesus on certain points. Hence Paul gave his personal opinion as a spirit-filled apostle. His counsel, however, was “God-breathed” and so came to form part of the Sacred Scriptures, having equal authority with the rest of those Scriptures.** [bold mine]

So while Paul was giving his opinion, it was given under the direction of the Holy Spirit which is from Jehovah God himself.

Answer (score 0):

> “But to the rest I, not the Lord, say: If any brother has a wife who
> does not believe, and she is willing to live with him, let him not
> divorce her. And a woman who has a husband who does not believe, if he
> is willing to live with her, let her not divorce him. For the
> unbelieving husband is sanctified by the wife, and the unbelieving
> wife is sanctified by the husband; otherwise, your children would be
> unclean, but now they are holy.”

The focus of verses 12-14 shifts from the union of two Christians to that of a Christian who is married to a non-believer.

There are a great many people who reject outright anything from Paul because what Paul has to say on a number of issues does not agree with what they believe to be true. The argument of “Pauline opinion” is touted in attempt to minimize Paul's instructions thus leaving the interpretation and the credibility of these revealed principles up to the individual reader.

1. The first thing one must understand here is that Paul is not denying inspiration connected with his words. He is merely pointing out that the issue he is now addressing is one that had not been previously addressed by the Lord. This does not mean that what Paul says on the matter is not by the inspiration of the Holy Spirit. This was a critical point that would have naturally developed especially among Jewish Christians, and this question was apparently one that had been submitted to Paul by the Church at Corinth for clarification. But what precisely is behind this instruction? Under the Law of Moses, the Jews were forbidden to marry one who was a foreigner (thus an idolater and an unbeliever) unless that person became a proselyte to the Jewish faith, a.k.a, a believer. In Ezra 10:3, when Judah was preparing to return to their own lands after 70 years of captivity, they were commanded to

> “make a covenant with our God to put away all these wives and those
> who have been born to them, according to the advice of my master and
> of those who tremble at the commandment of our God; and let it be done
> according to the law.”

Now, having become Christians where perhaps one spouse had become a believer and the other had not, they are instructed (both Jew and Gentile alike in the Church) to not put away their unbelieving spouse as long as the unbelieving spouse was content to remain with them.

2. The sanctity of the marriage union between a believer and a nonbeliever is upheld and blessed by the Lord. Even the children of that union are to be recognized as legitimate. The union is considered a holy union and the children of that union are sanctified.

The prerogative of the unbelieving spouse, 15

> “But if the unbeliever departs, let him depart; a brother or a sister
> is not under bondage in such cases. But God has called us to peace.”

1. The prerogative to leave is left solely to the unbelieving spouse, even if the believing spouse is content to remain. If the unbelieving spouse is not content to remain with a believer, they are free to leave, and the believing spouse has no alternative but to allow them to leave.
2. If the unbelieving spouse leaves, the believing spouse is then free of that marriage union. They are “not under bondage (no longer under obligation or constraint) in such cases.” That brother or sister is now free of that covenant. They are not the violator.